# How to get the auto generated ID of a doctrine entity and save it in a not associated table without flush the first one?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Given this scenario, It's possible to get the generated ID of the `entityA` or a way to inject it in the new entity without doing one flush() first? If the flush is not doing, the ID is always `null` because the entities are not associated each other.

```
<?php

    $a = new EntityA();
    $a->setName('hello');

    $em->persist($a);
    // $em->flush(); 

    $info = new EntityInfo();

    $info
        ->setReferenceClass(get_class($a))
        ->setReferenceId($a->getId());

    $em->persist($info);

    $em->flush();

?>
```

Comment: Does it work if you move `$em->persist($a);` just before `$em->persist($info);`?

Comment: No, there is not.  The id is actually generated by the database itself.  If your relations are mapped properly then Doctrine takes care of this for you.  Otherwise, you will need to generate the id yourself.

Comment: Thanks! As you say, In a entity collection for example, doctrine do the inserts and then the update of the objects in one mysql transaction. But my entities are not related, I was looking if doctrine provides a easy way to do the same.